# Create JSON data in specific format in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

i know there are many useful threads which teaches us how to make JSON data in a specific format. I have been looking into some useful threads but i am unable to achieve a specific format that i want. Can someone help me to achieve this format?

```
{"properties" : [
{"marker": {"point":new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479)   },
{lastvisit: "Timestamp":"2016-10-31 13:55"}
]}
```

I need to make data in this format and after then i will send it to the server as a POST request.

Comment: The Json structure shown above is an invalid structure. Please edit it

Comment: @SamuelRobert that's the thing. My client asked me to make data in this format. How can i make the above structure valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON structure was simply not valid (look at 'lastvisit: "Timestamp": "2016-10-31 13:55" for example). I'd recommend you to use http://jsonlint.com to validate your JSONs. it will make it easier for you in the future to locate the problems.

```
{
    "properties": [{
        "marker": {
            "point": new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479)
        },
        "lastvisit": {
            "Timestamp": "2016-10-31 13:55"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: thanks for making it easy for me as i was getting exactly this format when i was trying to make JSON formatted data.